# Laptop Wi-Fi disconnects as soon as I attempt to visit a website

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, laptop

I have a laptop which suddenly is no longer able to connect to Wi-Fi. I can join the network, and then it shows the typical wi-fi symbol on the taskbar for a while:

[image]

But then as soon as I attempt to visit a website or install a Windows update, it immediately disconnects. I tried "Network Reset" in Windows 10:

[image]

with no success (same problem after re-connecting to the network). I also tried restarting the laptop (both a restart and a complete power-down and power-on) with no success. None of my other laptops/desktops are having trouble connecting to Wi-Fi, it's just this one particular laptop for some reason.

I also tried "Diagnose this connection" for the wi-fi and I get an error 0x80004005:

[image]

**Any idea what else to try or what could be causing this?**

Comment: "which suddenly is no longer able to connect to Wi-Fi." What changed? A Windows or driver update? Installing a new app? 1. Try to find out what caused the issue, and back-out of that change. 2. Run SFC and DISM top check for file corruption. See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/an-error-has-occured-with-troubleshooter-error/b09390b0-3267-430a-85b5-75a944384807, also.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your modem and/or router?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing on my laptop. Turns out that WIFI card failed and any attempt to load it made it overheat and disconnect. Replacing WIFI card fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks. Is there anything else I can check to confirm this is problem?

Comment: Outher than replacing WIFI card for a new, working one - maybe checking if it is excessive hot (mine got discoloration on sticky paper were specifications are written). Touching with finger or attaching temp sensor when card is powered on may work but you have to know hot it becomes normally.
Please also check if antenna cables are plugged in. Those may (unlikely) disconnect with time or mechanicall stress.
Antenna cables might also completely break where cables go throught laptop hinges.